# How to set button control's position to be exactly in the middle of the window in Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently a noob for Win32 API and learning it. I want to learn how can we set the position of a button control to be exactly in the middle of the main window.

I am just creating a simple button like this in the `WM_CREATE` message of the `WndProc` function :-

```
HWND hBtn;

hBtn = CreateWindow
(
    L"Button", L"Hello",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    0, 0, 125, 50,
    hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
);
```

Note that `hBtn` is globally defined.

I am just subclassing the button control to get the hand cursor while hovering it. Its pretty simple.

```
SetWindowSubclass (hBtn, ButtonSubclass, NULL, NULL);
```

At last I just want the button to be exactly in the middle of the screen when the window is resized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only need to recalculate the position of the button in the [`WM_SIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) of the parent window to center it:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    hBtn = CreateWindow
    (
        L"Button", L"Hello",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        0, 0, 125, 50,
        hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
    );
    break;
case WM_SIZE:
{
    UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
    UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);
    RECT rc = {};
    GetClientRect(hBtn,&rc);
    int x = (int)(width - (rc.right - rc.left)) / 2;
    int y = (int)(height - (rc.bottom - rc.top)) / 2;
    MoveWindow(hBtn, x, y, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, 1);
}
break;
```

Comment: Hi, @Hitarth Padaliya, Does this answer your question? Please feel free to contact me if you have any issue and if this really helps you, please also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.

Comment: yup it did work for me. But I used a simple approach, used `LOWORD()` and `HIWORD()` for my use. It pretty much reduces the logic of reducing space from the window size and gives the client rect according. Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the left and top position of the button as the size of the parent window divided by two minus the size of the button divided by two. And then repaint and recalculate every time the window is resized.

Comment: Example https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/250672/CenterWindow-in-WIN32